# get items from database according to jlist selected values and store in array

Tags: java, sql, jlist

I have a table `Users` in my database with columns `phone no` and `region`. In my GUI, I have a `JList` from where the user can select one or more regions, and accordingly I need to send out messages to the phone numbers with matching region.

The problem I'm facing is in retrieving the phone numbers from the database.
This is my code

```
        final JList listRegion = new JList(list);
        listRegion.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        listRegion.setVisibleRowCount(3);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(listRegion);
        scroll.setBounds(113, 254, 123, 50);    
        frame.getContentPane().add(scroll);
```

I'm storing the selected list values like this

```
Object[] areaList = listRegion.getSelectedValues();
```

Now I need to retrieve all the numbers with their corresponding regions matching the regions in areaList and need to store them in an array.  I have tried something like this. But it seems to be wrong.

```
for( int i=0; i<areaList.length ; i++){
    String sql2 = "select phone_no from users where region = areaList["+i+"]";
    result = statement.executeQuery(sql2);

    while(result.next()){
        String numbers = result.getString(1);
        //System.out.println(numbers);
    }
}
```

I am poor with arrays. Hence not able to do it. Please guide me with the correct way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not able to access the `areaList` variable from sql. Probably you need something like (not tested):

```
String sql2 = "select phone_no from users where region in (";
for( int i=0; i<areaList.length ; i++){
    sql2 += "\'"+ areaList[i]+"\'";
    if (i<areaList.length-1)
        sql2+=",";
}
sql+=")";

result = statement.executeQuery(sql2);

while(result.next()){
        String numbers = result.getString(1);
        //System.out.println(numbers);
}
```

Also note that you should use a `PreparedStatement`, instead building the sql manually, this way you will be protected by sql injection issues.

Comment: It shows me this error `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')'`

Comment: @newbee You can add a `System.out.println("sql2: "+sql2);` before executing the query, to see how the query is build. My feeling is that the areaList[i] is not providing the proper value. Also see my updated answer, it was adding a `,` at the end that was not needed.

Comment: the query is being built correctly. `sql2: select phone_no from users where region in ('Mumbai',)`  and i had also checked areaList[i] by printing it in a loop. It works fine.

Comment: @newbee See my updated answer. The last `,` was the cause of the error.

Comment: Yup. It prints the phone numbers now :)  Can you also tell me how do I store all these extracted numbers in an array?

Comment: @newbee The simplest way is to use an `ArrayList` like: `ArrayList numbers=new ArrayList();` and then in the while loop you can do: `numbers.add(numbers);`